# Visual studio community 2022 "bug" in include C++ after update

Tags: c++, include

When I want to call a file using the #include code, instead of it showing me the files in my folder, it shows the windows kits files, this happened after the update, as old projects worked normally, and now they no longer work, somebody can help me?

I've already tried uninstalling, clearing system variables, changing the inclusion path, installing only what is necessary to use C++, but none of this works, it may seem like a silly mistake, but it gets in the way when I need to do something quickly
[image: problem]

[image: config]

Comment: Show  your project configs. The paths to the Windows development kit include files seem to be listed first there.

Comment: default configs, before working normal, now this happen

Comment: Although you have reinstalled visual studio, your user settings are kept unchanged. Ensure intellisense smart features are enabled.

Comment: What is default config? You told about custom include paths.

Comment: i I added an image of the inclusion configuration, which previously worked normally

Comment: Completely rebuild the projects. Pch cached files are not compatible between updates. Then try use competitions.

Comment: You show vs config, your project config is in C/C++

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting down votes, this is clearly an MS bug that has been introduced in a recent update,, now even a new empty project has the issue described here.

Comment: I guess they made it so Intellisense now behaves the same way the compiler [does/is supposed to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-170#remarks): all the paths covered by the `#include` angle-bracket form are also covered by the quoted form. Nonetheless, the fact the IDE now behaves this way is a pain in the neck; I just hope Microsoft will not consider the new behavior correct...

Comment: I would clean up files in local project. It is possible something get cached what new version of VS is unable to read.

Comment: This is confirmed to be a change that Microsoft decided to make for a few users that requested it. There is an active bug report for this on the [Visual Studio Community Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Include--is-now-behaving-the-same-as-/10538420#T-ND10539538) Up votes there may help to get this fixed.