# Visual Studio 2022 include bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Yesterday i've updated my visual studio 2022 to the latest version and now my quoted "" includes shows headers that are from vcruntime and not from the local proyect. Always these was shown by using angled includes <>, how i can fix this? Proyect is an empty template with all by default.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question has been asked already here, [Visual studio community 2022 "bug" in include C++ after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77539291/visual-studio-community-2022-bug-in-include-c-after-update)

Comment: It looks to be a MS bug to me, the only fix for now would be to revert to the last known working version, and then raise a VS community forum bug report.

Comment: @user20716902 you right has been already asked sorry i dint noticed about it, i been searching today on the web for a solution but nothing, i guess we will need to wait for MS to revert this changes it is a pain working this way.

Comment: Issue has been raised on the Visual Studio Community Forum, [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Include--is-now-behaving-the-same-as-/10538420), upvotes there may help get this addressed quickly.

Comment: Does it happen also for new project? I would try clean old project. Some cached data generated by old VS may not be readable by new version of VS leading to this problem.

Comment: @MarekR yes, the attached images are from a proyect created today, i through it maybe was my old ones but happends on every single proyect you create, not even updating to the preview version of visual studio works.

Comment: The problem is not solved currently. Day Jan 6 update,  the suggestion has been queued up for prioritization.